# Read a file using location from properties file

Tags: java, file, io, readfile

I have one file that is stored in C:/file.txt. The properties file `location.properties` contains only the path i.e C:/file.txt. I want to read the properties file, get the location , read the file and display everything.
But I am getting fileNotFound exception. Can anybody help me? This is my code:

```
package com.tcs.fileRead;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ReadFile {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties prop = new Properties();

        try {

            prop.load(new FileInputStream("location.properties"));
            //prop.load(fileIn);
            String loc = prop.getProperty("fileLoc");
            System.out.println(loc);

            BufferedReader buffer;
            buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(loc));
            String line;
            while((line =buffer.readLine())!= null)
            {
                System.out.println(line);
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

This is the output:

```
"C:\file.txt"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\file.txt" (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:156)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:69)
    at com.tcs.fileRead.ReadFile.main(ReadFile.java:29)
```

Comment: Why does your path have quotes around it? Quotes are not valid in a path on WIndows (and never used on other platforms either, although it's possible)

Comment: Thanks. I have put "" in the properties file which is wrong. :) @immibis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the path surrounded with quotes in your properties file, so you are trying to open `"C:\file.txt"` (which is not a valid path) instead of `C:\file.txt`.